# Can an attributive noun add identity to a noun phrase?

Tags: attributive-nouns

I'm in the process of writing documentation. I'm making use of attributive nouns to describe business-specific concepts and entities.

There's one entity in particular which I'm currently referring to as the "details page" (a page that displays a product's details). I'm trying to understand whether I'm using attributive nouns properly.

In contrast to a noun phrase such as "sports car", where the attributive noun "sports" adds ideas such as speed and power to create a new general concept (a high performance vehicle), in "details page" the word "details" is used to distinguish this particular page from all other pages. There's no general concept of *a* details page in my domain, it is only used to refer to *the* details page. It assigns identity to "page".

In this context, is "details" an attributive noun? Should it be capitalized? Somehow "details page" *feels* different to "sports car" but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: I don't see the difference. Just as you might distinguish a product description "details page" from a "user reviews page", you might have to decide whether to use your "sports car" or your "family saloon car" to drive to work. We don't normally capitalise a noun phrase just because it happens to include an "attributive noun" (or any other kind of word used adjectively, including ordinary adjectives such as *the **first** page, the **red** car*).

Comment: I'd recommend the terminology given at [compounds and phrases ... compound nouns vs free combinations vs collocations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227429/compounds-and-phrases-compound-nouns-vs-free-combinations-collocations/227438#227438). It is also stated there that accurate separation of strings of matrix nouns into such classes is often disputed. Nowadays, dictionaries help by listing open compounds. But the semantic connection between [N₁] and [N₂] in the string [N₁ N₂] can take very diverse forms. Plastic fork. Football manager. Summer flower. Bargain basement....

Answer (score 2):

You are still using an *attributive noun*, that is, a noun modifying another noun rather like an adjective would (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)).

Some attributive nouns form noun phrases recognized widely enough that, over time, users recognize them as a general concept. Dictionaries may even recognize them as their own lexeme, since the usage may be distinct from how one would parse the phrase literally:

- [sports car](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sports%20car)
- [seat belt](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seat%20belt)
- [web page](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/web%20page)
- [goose egg](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/goose%20egg)

Most noun phrases formed with attributive nouns don't undergo this extra development. One can generate many noun phrases using attributive nouns to fit specific situations. For *page* alone you could have:

- *details page*
- *contacts page*
- *information page*
- *resource page*
- *company page*
- *product page*

So the difference may be that you don't understand *details page* in as restrictive a way you understand *sports car*.